# Spring JdbcTemplate Insert throws uncategorized SQLException

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am inserting a new row into a table with Spring JDBCTemplate. The jdbcTemplate.update() throws the following exception:

> PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [99999]; error code [17090]; operation not allowed

But the row is inserted into the db anyway.

Here's the code:

```
final StringBuilder widgetInsert = new StringBuilder();
widgetInsert.append("INSERT INTO WIDGET (ID, KEY, DEPT_NUM, TYPE, CREATED_BY_ID, CREATED_DATE) ");
widgetInsert.append("VALUES (WIDGET_SEQ.NEXTVAL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ");

Long widgetId;
try {
    KeyHolder kh = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
    jdbcTemplate.update(
            new PreparedStatementCreator() {
                @Override
                public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
                    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(widgetInsert.toString());
                    ps.setLong(1, key);
                    ps.setLong(2, deptNumber);
                    ps.setString(3, widgetType);
                    ps.setLong(4, creatorId);
                    ps.setLong(5, System.currentTimeMillis());
                    return ps;
                }
            }, kh);
    widgetId = kh.getKey().longValue();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // THIS EXCEPTION IS THROWN
    throw new WidgetException("Problem inserting widget for key=" + key, e);
}
```

EDIT:
Running Spring JDBC 3.2.4.RELEASE

Full exception:

> [21] 15/02/02 15:04:59.537 In StandardWrapperValve.invoke(): [127] org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [99999]; error code [17090]; operation not allowed; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: operation not allowed
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:83)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:605)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:849)
>       at org.acme.widget.service.WidgetServiceImpl.createWidget(WidgetServiceImpl.java:68)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.getOrCreatePersonalOwner(Unknown Source)
>       at org.acme.service.BigServiceImpl.addStuff(BigServiceImpl.java:574)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.addStuff(Unknown Source)
>       at org.acme.endpoint.BigRs.addStuff(BigRs.java:262)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:440)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:428)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.acme.stack.auth.spring.AuthRequestParameterCleanupFilter.doFilter(AuthRequestParameterCleanupFilter.java:45)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.acme.stack.auth.spring.AuthContextSpringFilter.doFilter(AuthContextSpringFilter.java:90)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:94)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.acme.stack.web.servlet.filter.SessionlessFilter.doFilter(SessionlessFilter.java:30)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:203)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:683)
>       at org.acme.stack.tomcat.auth.AuthHostValve.invoke(AuthHostValve.java:145)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: operation not allowed
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getGeneratedKeys(OracleStatement.java:5219)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.getGeneratedKeys(OracleStatementWrapper.java:366)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractQueryReport$StatementProxy.invoke(AbstractQueryReport.java:235)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89.getGeneratedKeys(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractQueryReport$StatementProxy.invoke(AbstractQueryReport.java:235)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89.getGeneratedKeys(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementDecoratorInterceptor$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementDecoratorInterceptor.java:252)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89.getGeneratedKeys(Unknown Source)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$3.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:854)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$3.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:849)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:589)
>       ... 96 more

Comment: Can you post with the full error message? I tested with H2 with no problem. Also what's your spring-jdbc version?

Comment: Full test code is [here](https://gist.github.com/chenrui333/909d1ea9da137aca7dab)

Comment: See edits, I'm unable to run your code due to Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: URL format error; must be "jdbc:h2:{ {.|mem:}[name] | [file:]fileName | {tcp|ssl}:[//]server[:port][,server2[:port]]/name }[;key=value...]" but is "jdbc:h2:mem:test" [90046-144]

Comment: If it works for you I'm wondering if the problem is Oracle-specific since I am running on Oracle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, this is solved for me. It may be an Oracle requirement - I don't know that for sure since I've not been able to run chenrui's test code on H2. Apparently the PreparedStatement requires the sequenced column(s) to be explicitly declared. So for my primary key column generated off the sequence I declare as follows:

```
    final String generatedColumns[] = { "ID" };
```

I then pass the array into my prepareStatement() call inside the createPreparedStatement() method of the PreparedStatementCreator anonymous inner class:

```
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(widgetInsert.toString(), generatedColumns);
```

Answer (score 4):

I have faced the same problem when using `org.springframework.jdbc.object.BatchSqlUpdate`
in my code:

```
BatchSqlUpdate batchSqlUpdate = new BatchSqlUpdate(dataSource, getSqlString(), getSqlTypes(), 1);
KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();

long result;
int row = batchSqlUpdate.update(getObjParameters(tmpObj), keyHolder);
if (row > 0) 
    result = keyHolder.getKey().longValue();
```

It caused this error:

> SQL state [99999]; error code [17090]; operation not allowed; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: operation not allowed

I added these 2 lines before executing the update operation and the problem has been resolved:

```
batchSqlUpdate.setGeneratedKeysColumnNames(new String[]{"id"});
batchSqlUpdate.setReturnGeneratedKeys(true);
```